# Building Grid with Flexbox - Items in second row only on right Side

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

i want to build my Grid with Flexbox and get stucked a little bit. 
It is a 4-Column Grid. In the Second Row i only want to place 2 Items on the right Side.
Just see my Scribble.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Multiline */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Align to the right */
}
.flex > div {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not check, to set the DIV to 25%. You allready helped on my other questions. Thanks very much!!! :)